# cordova_plugins.json not found

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, sencha-touch-2.1

I am using Sencha Touch 2.1 with PhoneGap 2.7.0 so that I can package it for iOS. The app loads fine until I package it with Sencha CMD by running `sencha app build package`.

In both the regular and package version in the javascript console I see `cordova_plugins.json 404 (Not Found)`

I added cordova-2.7.0.js in the root of the app and edited app.json to include it like below. Any idea what could be the issue?

```
"js": [
    {
        "path": "cordova-2.7.0.js"
    },
    {
        "path": "resources/js/infobubble-compiled.js"
    },
    {
        "path": "touch/sencha-touch.js"
    },
    {
        "path": "app.js",
        "bundle": true,  /* Indicates that all class dependencies are concatenated into this file when build */
        "update": "delta"
    }
],
```

Comment: possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/a/16139562/924143