# IBM Worklight 6.0 - How to manipulate Cordova.js file?

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I am having [this same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16783054/2566003) but when I try to change the cordova.js file within my Android environment, the file is being rewritten during build.

Is there a way to permanently delete the last block of code?

Comment: if this answer helped you resolve your problem, please mark it as Answered.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot alter the Cordova files.

The "cordova_plugins.json" 404 error you're seeing is harmless and will not affect your application in any way.

Newer Cordova releases no longer show this error. In a future Worklight release the bundled Cordova will be upgraded as well and this harmless  error will also not be present in Worklight.

As written in the link in your question:

> Filip Maj of Adobe has said elsewhere that this is due to (so far)
>   partially implemented plugin tooling. In future versions of Cordova,
>   the plugin tooling will generate cordova_plugins.json itself.
>
> For now, he has said it's save to completely ignore the 404 error.

A workaround for it if you really can't ignore the 404 error is to **add a dummy cordova_plugins.json file** to the android folder in your project (yourProject\apps\yourApp\android).

My suggest: ignore it.