# Phonegap - Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/cordova_plugins.json

Tags: javascript, android, json, cordova

I am about to set up a phonegap project and wanted to create a little hello world application to make sure my phonegap app works alright. For this I am printing out some device information. Here is my JavaScript code:

```
 function onDeviceReady(){
     document.getElementById("name").innerHTML      = device.name; // undefined
     document.getElementById("phonegap").innerHTML  = device.phonegap; // undefined
     document.getElementById("platform").innerHTML  = device.platform; // Android
     document.getElementById("version").innerHTML   = device.version; // 4.4.2
     document.getElementById("uuid").innerHTML      = device.uuid; // 1dafa426...
   }

   /** Called at the bodys onLoad event */
   function init(){
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
   }
```

As soon as I run this code I get the following error message:

> Unable to open asset URL:
>   file:///android_asset/www/cordova_plugins.json

I have tried commenting out the device.name and device.phonegap lines, but this couldn't fix it.

Any ideas to fix this? I am using Cordova 2.9.0 and have attached both my config.xml file and my full error log.

---

config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns     = "..."
        id        = "io.cordova.helloCordova"
        version   = "2.0.0">
    <name>Hello Cordova</name>

    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>

    <author href="..." email="dev@cordova.apache.org">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>

    <access origin="*"/>

    <!-- <content src="..." /> for external pages -->
    <content src="index.html" />

    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
    <!--
      <preference name="splashscreen" value="resourceName" />
      <preference name="backgroundColor" value="0xFFF" />
      <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="20000" />
      <preference name="InAppBrowserStorageEnabled" value="true" />
      <preference name="disallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    -->

    <feature name="App">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Geolocation">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Device">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Device"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Accelerometer">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.AccelListener"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Compass">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.CompassListener"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Media">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.AudioHandler"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Camera">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Contacts">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.ContactManager"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="File">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.FileUtils"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="NetworkStatus">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Notification">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Storage">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Storage"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="FileTransfer">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Capture">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Capture"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Battery">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.BatteryListener"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="SplashScreen">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Echo">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Echo"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Globalization">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Globalization"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="InAppBrowser">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser"/>
    </feature>
    <!-- Deprecated plugins element. Remove in 3.0 -->
    <plugins>
    </plugins>
</widget>
```

---

The CatLog:

```
D/CordovaWebView(8703): CordovaWebView is running on device made by: LGE
D/JsMessageQueue(8703): Set native->JS mode to 2
D/CordovaActivity(8703): CordovaActivity.init()
D/CordovaWebView(8703): >>> loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
D/PluginManager(8703): init()
D/CordovaWebView(8703): >>> loadUrlNow()
D/Config(8703): Unlimited access to network resources
I/CordovaLog(8703): Found start page location: index.html
I/CordovaLog(8703): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
D/CordovaActivity(8703): Resuming the App
D/CordovaActivity(8703): CB-3064: The errorUrl is null
D/CordovaActivity(8703): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
I/ActivityManager(770): Displayed sample/.HelloPhonegap: +254ms
E/AndroidProtocolHandler(8703): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/cordova_plugins.json
D/Cordova(8703): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
D/CordovaActivity(8703): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
E/AndroidProtocolHandler(8703): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/cordova_plugins.js
```

**EDIT (Workaround)**

Creating a dummy file cordova_plugins.json helped me to get rid of my error messages. This seems just to be a little workaround and I still have got the problem that I cannot access the variables device.name and device.phonegap (They're undefined).

**EDIT (Upgrade to Cordova 3.x)**

After upgrading my project to cordova 3.x this error disappeared. Maybe I did just make any mistake in setting up the project. Nevertheless everything works totally fine with Cordova 3.x (I updated to 3.1 and later on to 3.4)

Comment: Does the file `www/cordova_plugins.json` exist?

Comment: BTW http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16095757/what-is-the-cordova-plugins-json-file-for-cordova-is-requesting-it-at-initializ/16139562

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16139562/366346

Comment: It does not. I looked this up and it looks like both the cordova_plugins.json and the cordova_plugins.js get automatically created by phonegap.

Comment: Thanks for your answers ! I also read these before. Creating a dummy cordova_plugins.json file, I could in deed get rid of my error message, but am still not able to access the device.name variable...